# Why is tf.GradientTape.jacobian giving None?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gradient, gradienttape

I'm using the IRIS dataset, and am following this official tutorial: [Custom training: walkthrough](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough.ipynb)

In the Training loop, I am trying to gather the model outputs and weights in each `epoch%50==0` in the lists `m_outputs_mod50, gather_weights` respectively:

```
# Keep results for plotting
train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []
m_outputs_mod50 = []
gather_weights = []
num_epochs = 201

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  epoch_loss_avg = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
  epoch_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
  # gather_kernel(model)
  # Training loop - using batches of 32
  for x, y in train_dataset:
    # Optimize the model
    loss_value, grads = grad(model, x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    # Track progress
    epoch_loss_avg.update_state(loss_value)  # Add current batch loss
    # Compare predicted label to actual label
    # training=True is needed only if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    epoch_accuracy.update_state(y, model(x, training=True))

  # End epoch
  train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
  train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())

  # pred_hist.append(model.predict(x))

  if epoch % 50 == 0:
    m_outputs_mod50.append(model(x))
    gather_weights.append(model.weights)
    print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(epoch,
                                                                epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                                epoch_accuracy.result()))
```

Running the above and trying to even get the jacobian at epoch 0 (using `m_outputs_mod50[0]` and `gather_weights[0]`) using

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  print(tape.jacobian(target = m_outputs_mod50[0], sources = gather_weights[0]))`
```

I get a list of None as the output.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the GradientTape operates. For that, you can follow the guide: [Introduction to gradients and automatic differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff). Here is an excerpt:

> TensorFlow provides the `tf.GradientTape` API for automatic
> differentiation; that is, computing the gradient of a computation with
> respect to some inputs, usually `tf.Variables`. TensorFlow "records"
> relevant operations executed inside the context of a `tf.GradientTape`
> onto a "tape". TensorFlow then uses that tape to compute the gradients
> of a "recorded" computation using reverse mode differentiation.

To compute a gradient (or a jacobian), the tape needs to record the operations that are executed in its context. Then, outside its context, once the *forward pass* has been executed, its possible to use the tape to compute the gradient/jacobian.

You could use something like that:

```
if epoch % 50 == 0:
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    out = model(x)
  jacobian = tape.jacobian(out, model.weights)
```